# unbrick Nano RP2040 connect using Uno

Tags: arduino-nano

I think I have bricked my Nano RP2040. How do I unbrick using a Uno or Mega? I found instructions for using another Nano, but only have the one.

Comment: are you certain that the unbricking instructions are Nano specific?

Comment: I don't think you can unbrick it like a regular Arduino Nano, since there isn't a bootloader that is programmed into the RP2040 chip.

Answer (score 3):

You don't actually need a Uno or mega to unbrick the device.
You need to place a jumper wire between the GND and REC pins.
This will force the bootloader to load, a mass-storage device will appear on the computer. You can than upload a UF2 file to the drive to restore it.

You can read more about it in the arduino documentation.
https://docs.arduino.cc/tutorials/nano-rp2040-connect/rp2040-01-technical-reference#forcing-bootloader

If it is really bad you might also need to use a flash_nuke.uf2 file first. This removes all files on the Arduino Nano RP2040 connect.

Comment: Thank you, Bonnom. Got the Nano working again.